# Is there a performance issue if we increase maxStringContentLength to 200000000 in WCF Client configuration file?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

I get this exception when I use the default binding settings in configuration file.

The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.

I was able to resolve the error by increasing the maxStringContentLength to 200000000. I also increased the other max sizes to 200000000 as shown below. I am not sure if changing the max sizes randomly to a larger number will cause any performance issues? Do I need to figure out the ideal max sizes depending on how much data will be sent or received in my case? Thank you for any advice.

```
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="EPSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="200000000" maxArrayLength="200000000"
            maxBytesPerRead="200000000" maxNameTableCharCount="200000000" />
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Just calculate the size of the buffer size of 200,000,000 for a `String` and you will figure out this will cause a performance problem.  You are telling the configuration file to allow your system to read 200,000,000 bytes INTO MEMORY by setting `maxBytesPerRead` to 200,000,000 that is just overkill.  I STRONGLY suggest you do research on what those configuration options actually do beause you wouldn't likely be asking this question if you did.